# How can I retrieve struct from nested array in solidity?

Tags: multidimensional-array, typeerror, solidity

I want to grab my `User` out of the nested `gameBoard` array so that I can move it to a new index set of `x` and `y`. Remix IDE throws this error: `TypeError: type struct Game.User storage ref[] storage ref is not implicitly convertible to expected type struct Game.User memory`. I originally tried this without the `memory`, but not only does that go against the goal of not storing it permanently (if I understand it correctly), but also it threw less useful errors. Please help!

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

contract Game {
    struct User{
        address owner;
        uint currency;
        uint left;
        uint right;
        uint top;
        uint bottom;
    }
    User[][10][10] public gameBoard;

    function addUser (uint _x, uint _y) public {
        gameBoard[_x][_y].push(User(msg.sender, 10, 5, 5, 5, 5));
    }

    function moveUser (uint _fromX, uint _fromY, uint _toX, uint _toY) public {
        User memory mover = gameBoard[_fromX][_fromY];
        if (mover.owner != msg.sender)return;

        // once I have 'mover', I will check whether
        // I want its the msg.senders and then place
        // it where I want it to go
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Short Answer: You are indexing your array wrong, and need another set of [brackets].

So you created a 3 dimensional array of users called "gameboard".  When adding a user you push a struct into the dynamic 3rd dimension of your array correctly.  However when you access the structs, you only give two dimensions and so Solidity returns the dynamic user array.  Since you are trying to store it into a struct rather than an array of structs the error is being thrown.  The easiest way to fix it is to use:

```
User memory mover = gameBoard[_fromX][_fromY][0];
```

However this only returns the first user at that position on the game board so you'll probably need to do some sort of looping (which isn't ideal in contracts).  Personally I prefer to stay away from multidimensional arrays, and honestly all arrays in  general (although they have their uses) when working with Solidity.  Mappings are usually a lot easier to work with, especially when working with addresses.  Could you possibly elaborate on what you are attempting to do in case there is a better way of achieving it?

Comment: Hey, thanks so much. I was able to change the code to adjust to just a 2D array (my original goal).

As far as elaboration, my goal is to keep track of the pieces on a 2D game board. If arrays are computationally heavy, I guess I could use mappings, but since you can't use mappings, I imagine I would need to do some duplication of information? (ownerAddress => xyString), (xyString => ownerAddress), (ownerAddress => characterStruct)?

The game is played by adding users to the board. Users can battle to switch places. So I have to track a user struct->owner, owner->spot, and spot->owner.

Comment: Happy to hear that your problem is solved!  Not sure what you mean by "but since you can't use mappings, I imagine I would need to do some duplication of information".  Are you saying you can't use two dimensional mappings, because you are allowed to.  Mappings can store mappings as the values, just not as the keys.

If this is what you mean, you could instead do: `mapping(uint8 => mapping(uint8 => UserStore))`